# Elle s'appelle comment?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

> If you can't get anything from colours, [try something else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lCCK.jpg)

Comment: Is the answer a play on words that requires an understanding of French?

Comment: Elle s'appelle Violet. Clearly.

Comment: Just a note: in French, the *t* is silent when it is *violet*. So, her name would be *Violette*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Je ne sais pas comment elle s'apelle*. But I've got a solution.

The words VIOLENT CURSOR ...

> ... are an anagram of "invert colours". So we must invert the colours. For the hex values Beastly Gerbil has already helpfully provided in his answer that means we have to take `#ff - x` instead of `x`. (The hint links to the image of an anime character called Ana Gram. I needed the hint, which is a bit embarassing in hindsight, because I had seen that all the hex numbers are in a narrow range and are all greater that `#80`.)
>
>  Converting the inverted colour values to ASCII yields:
>
>     *Very well done! She is one "nerdy evil dicer".*
>
>  I guess that her name is an anagram of "nerdy evil dicer". I couldn't find one, but Will could. He has found out the she is one **very nice riddle**.
>
>  (With the question in the title – "What's her name?" in French – I had somehow expected a French name.)

Comment: It's not quite Cruella de Ville ...

Comment: Nor is it Cinderella, although there might be something cinder-y going on. (I would like it to be "Le Cÿndriër Vide", the Empty Ashtray, a French metal band I've just made up.)

Comment: Well done! I tried anagramming violent cursor but didn't get anything

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: I had tried that earlier, too, but probably only half-heartedly. The new hint made me look more thoroughly. Thanks for the useful list of colours!

Comment: I think it's just supposed to be "very nice riddle." :/

Comment: @Will: Yes, that's probably it, even if it doesn't quite fit the question in the title.

Comment: Well done! you too @Will

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will help, but the colours make me suspicious..

The values of the colours are:

> ```
> A99A8D - 86DF88 - 9A9393 - DF9B90
>
> 919ADE - DFAC97 - 9ADF96 - 8CDF90
>
> 919ADF - DD919A - 8D9B86 - DF9A89
>
> 9693DF - 9B969C - 9A8DDD - D1DFDF
> ```

They don't give anything when translated to ASCII or hexadecimal and the fact there is no [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) tag, probably suggests this isn't helpful. But the colours *are* weird...

EDIT:

The cipher tag was edited and MOehm got that step

Comment: Tell me if this is the wrong track @incesterror21

Comment: I thought about assigning a colour to each letter and there re-arranging the colours to somehow form an anagram but there are more coloured boxes than letters.

Answer (score 1):

> Elle s'appelle violet.

Because *Elle s'appelle comment* in french means

> What is it called?

And a violent curser is well, violent, and a simply play on words changes

> Violent to violet (the french word meaning purple), further, purple is the color taking the most of the grid in the background image.

Someone mentioned this in the comments, as well, I can't remember exactly who it was.

Comment: Rather than what is it called, it means "what is she called".

Comment: @stackreader, guess I need to brush up on my french, but for now, my answer stands

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this is supposed to be an answer to the puzzle, but since I don't have enough points to post comments yet, I'm posting this as an answer:

When translating "Elle s'appelle comment ?" from French to English, it's correct to translate it to "What is she called" or "What's her name?" since the two are used in English. However, it literally translates more correctly to

- "She herself calls how?" (More logically "She calls herself how?")
- or: "She herself calls what?" (More logically "She calls herself what?")

The version of "Herself" used in French doesn't exist in English to my knowledge, but the s' (before appelle) is short for "se", which can refer to both genders. A more precise translation of the french "se" would be the English word "self" alone.

Hope this helps somehow, and again: Sorry for posting as an answer - I hope I don't get punished for this..

EDIT: First attempt to answer the puzzle (a very simple one)

Merely answering "the question" with French versions of the words and a French word order = **Elle s'appelle Curseur Violent**.

Comment: Just add an answer based off of your information and I think it would be fine :P